# Kafka consumer group lag: Initial and low throughout case problem

Tags: apache-kafka, sarama

### Use case:

- Producer: Writes to Kafka at topic `db.inventory.customers`
- ConsumerGroup1 (cg1): Reads from `db.inventory.customers` and writes to `loader-b.inventory.customers`
- ConsumerGroup2 (cg2): Reads from `loader-b.inventory.customers` and writes to Github.

#### Monitor lags and do some work

We monitor cg1 lag and cg2 lag. When lag is in the range `0 <= lag <= 100` for both the consumer groups, we do some **task**.

#### Problem

Problem is for the loader topic with low throughput the cg2 disappears, so we do not know its lag and consider it as -1. Our condition is never met and we are stuck.

Now if we consider the condition as
`0 <= lag <= 100` for cg1
and `-1 <= lag <= 100` for cg2

Then, in the very first run when cg2 is not created also, it will consider the condition met. But we do not want that. We want it to do some work and then lag should come to condition.

What should I do?

### Code

```golang
func (t *kafkaWatch) consumerGroupLag(
    id string,
    topic string,
    partition int32,
    broker *sarama.Broker,
) (
    int64,
    error,
) {
    defaultLag := int64(-1)

    lastOffset, err := t.client.GetOffset(topic, partition, sarama.OffsetNewest)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultLag, fmt.Errorf("Error getting offset for topic partition: %s, err: %v", topic, err)
    }

    offsetFetchRequest := sarama.OffsetFetchRequest{
        ConsumerGroup: id,
        Version:       1,
    }
    offsetFetchRequest.AddPartition(topic, partition)

    err = broker.Open(t.client.Config())
    if err != nil && err != sarama.ErrAlreadyConnected {
        return defaultLag, fmt.Errorf("Error opening broker connection again, err: %v", err)
    }

    offsetFetchResponse, err := broker.FetchOffset(&offsetFetchRequest)
    if err != nil {
        return defaultLag, fmt.Errorf(
            "Error fetching offset for offsetFetchRequest: %s %v, err: %v",
            topic, offsetFetchRequest, err)
    }
    if offsetFetchResponse == nil {
        return defaultLag, fmt.Errorf(
            "OffsetFetch request got no response for request: %+v",
            offsetFetchRequest)
    }

    for topicInResponse, partitions := range offsetFetchResponse.Blocks {
        if topicInResponse != topic {
            continue
        }

        for partitionInResponse, offsetFetchResponseBlock := range partitions {
            if partition != partitionInResponse {
                continue
            }
            // Kafka will return -1 if there is no offset associated
            // with a topic-partition under that consumer group
            if offsetFetchResponseBlock.Offset == -1 {
                klog.V(4).Infof("%s not consumed by group: %v", topic, id)
                return defaultLag, nil
            }
            if offsetFetchResponseBlock.Err != sarama.ErrNoError {
                return defaultLag, fmt.Errorf(
                    "Error since offsetFetchResponseBlock.Err != sarama.ErrNoError for offsetFetchResponseBlock.Err: %+v",
                    offsetFetchResponseBlock.Err)
            }
            return lastOffset - offsetFetchResponseBlock.Offset, nil
        }
    }

    klog.Warningf("%s for group is not active or present in Kafka", topic)
    return defaultLag, nil
}
```

Comment: Store the cache of the lags and work on it, til the consumer group comes back. Working out well for us.